# How to get data based on two columns from same table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to retrieve some data from a table based on two columns see the below table structure

**Update**
    i want the output data based on two condition 
    1. if the code value is having 'Web' or 'Offline'. 
    2. Memo column is having data same as Pre_memo column.

[image: Table]

Output should be as shown below

[image: Output]

So far i got the output by using same table two times but i wanted to get the output result by **using the table only 1 time** to avoid performance related issues as this table is having huge data.

```
select distinct OrderTable.Memo,
max(OrderTable.Memo_Date) as Date1,
max(ot.Pre_Memo_Date) as Date2
from OrderTable,
OrderTable ot
where OrderTable.code in ('Web')
and ot.code in ('Offline')
and OrderTable.Memo = ot.Pre_Memo
group by OrderTable.Memo
```

Can anyone help on this?  With the use of OrderTable only once in the query and filter based on memo and pre_memo column as it's having same data?

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: @jarlh i need help to get the output using the table only one time in above query i used OrderTable two times with alias.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Depending on your RDBMS, this might be straightforward or impossible (e.g. for MySQL). So please tag your question accordingly (as suggested by @YogeshSharma)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and do the *conditional* aggregation :

```
select Memo, max(case when code = 'Offline' then Date end) as Memo_date,
             max(case when code = 'Web' then Date end) as Per_Memo_date
from (select Date, 'Web' as code, Pre_memo as Memo
      from OrderTable o
      where code = 'Web'
      union all
      select Date, 'Offline', Memo
      from OrderTable o
      where code = 'Offline'
    ) t
group by Memo;
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not giving the correct output It's returning 5212 records with some blank date field where it should be 4659 records, also in the above query there is no filteration for pre_memo and Memo column like below

OrderTable.Memo = ot.Pre_Memo

Comment: in where clause filteration is based on code column not on memo and pre_memo column

Answer (score 0):

"I wanted to retrieve some data from a table based on two columns see the below table structure"

Providing a sample is sufficient to *illustrate* the problem (and it is desirable to do so on SO) but it is not sufficient and thus not a replacement for *defining* the problem, which you have failed to do.

Absent such *definition* of the problem, we can only *guess* what you're trying to achieve.  E.G.

- from the subset of tuples that have 'Offline' for 'code' value, take the MAX() 'Date' value per appearing value of 'Memo'.
- Match that (using some matching condition) to the subset of tuples that have 'Web' for 'code value and retain the 'Date' value from those as 'Memo_date' in the result set.
- matching condition being that 'Memo' value of [a tuple in] the former is equal to 'Pre_memo' value in [the matching tuple in] the latter.

If all that is correct, then that explains why it is *impossible* to do this in SQL without having at least two references.  You cannot avoid doing *some kind of* matching, and matching by definition takes two distinct things to match (even if the two distinct things are distinct subsets of one and the same thing).  In fact it is almost certainly a fundamental design mistake for you to have those two distinct things in one single table, probably under the totally misguided belief that "having everything in one table makes things easier".

"So far i got the output by using same table two times but i wanted to get the output result by using the table only 1 time to avoid performance related issues as this table is having huge data"

From the way you have presented the question, I suspect that you were hoping for some means to exploit the fact that those 'Offline' tuples are "the next" after a 'Web' tuple, and that you could write the SQL in such a way that the engine could then derive a sort of "single pass" algorithm (which you probably *assume* would go faster).

It does not work like that.  SQL tables have *no inherent ordering* and as a consequence there simply ain't no such thing as "the next" in a table.

Comment: While it's true that SQL tables have no inherent ordering, the OP's data seems to be ordered by (date, code). If that's indeed the case and if the OP's RDBMS supports windowing functions (which essentially all major RDBMS except for MySQL do), it's indeed possible to solve this with a single table scan.

Comment: I know of LAG() and the like, thank you.  What in the OP's problem statement provides you with *guarantee* that the mere ordering by date *will* bring you to a matching 'Offline' tuple starting from a 'Web' one ?  In fact, if there is indeed "ordering by date and code" and "this table is having huge data" as the OP stated himself, isn't that a full guarantee that for each date there will first be a mass of 'Web' tuples, thus already breaking your point ?

Comment: @Erwin Smout i want the output data based on two condition 

1. if the code value is having 'Web' or 'Offline'.
2. Memo column is having data same as Pre_memo column

Comment: @ErwinSmout You're right - there's no *guarantee* regarding that (that's why I wrote *If that's indeed the case*), and without further information from the OP, it's pointless to discuss what might and might not be true regarding the data set.